# ruby was-sdk v2 : Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError Exception: SSL_connect

Tags: ruby, ssl, ssl-certificate, aws-sdk

I downloaded the ca-bundle.crt from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt
and installed it on my OS X Yosemite (10.10 w Ruby 2.2.1)  local computer at /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt, as the was-sdk v2 is not anymore shipped with an SSL CA bundle

However, executing :

```
 @s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(credentials: Aws.config[:credentials] )
 puts @s3.list_buckets()
```

I get an error

```
 *** Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError Exception: SSL_connect 
returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate 
B: certificate verify failed
```

I tried wo success to add the ca-bundle.cert path to my Aws.config

```
 Aws.config[:ssl_ca_bundle] = '/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt'
```

I also tried to disable the ssl peer verification (for test purpose only)

```
 Aws.config[:ssl_verify_peer] = false
```

But in both tests it's still failing ..

I read some issues posted about this topic, but none related to the final v2 version ... what could be  the 'definitive' solution to this issue ? 
thanks for feedback

Comment: If you have installed Ruby with RVM as a binary and OpenSSL with Homebrew, then there's a mismatch between these two. See this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901864/troubleshooting-ssl-certificates-ruby-mac-os-x-yosemite/33035529#33035529

Comment: the mismatch fix linked above resolved my issue. thanks @PetrusRepo

Answer (score 2):

It's an OS X / Homebrew  issue ... 
install openssl w Homebrew the CA cert is located at : /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem

so I need to configure it :

```
 Aws.config[:ssl_ca_bundle] = '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem'
```