# Troubleshooting SSL certificates, Ruby, Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: ruby, macos, ssl, osx-yosemite

On OS X Mavericks, I am getting the following error from my Ruby programs when I try to connect to various APIs:

```
Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 
    state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

What is the recommended solution to this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby was-sdk v2 : Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError Exception: SSL\_connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318874/ruby-was-sdk-v2-seahorseclientnetworkingerror-exception-ssl-connect)

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was the following:

- Ruby installed as a binary with RVM assumed OpenSSL is in /etc/openssl
- OpenSSL had been installed with Homebrew to /usr/local/etc/openssl

=> Mismatch; and symlinking /etc/openssl -> /usr/local/etc/openssl did not help.

Compile RVM Ruby from sources: 
`rvm install VERSION --disable-binary`

After that, make sure your certificates are up-to-date: 
`rvm osx-ssl-certs update`