# Paperclip and S3 (Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have troubles getting S3/Paperclip up and running. Error I get:

```
Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError 
  (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed)
```

My config looks like:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_host_name: "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: "my-buckt-name",
      access_key_id: "NOT-TELLING-YOU",
      secret_access_key: "NOT-TELLING-YOU-EITHER",
      s3_region: "s3-eu-west-1",
    }
  }
```

When I disable cert verification, it works and I can upload my files.

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

It also works with the more specific version

```
Aws.config[:ssl_verify_peer] = false
```

Of course this is not the way to go, but shows that the config *seems* to be right.

I read following:

https://www.bountysource.com/issues/36571057-seahorse-client-networkingerror-ssl_connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-error-certificate-verify-failed

[Troubleshooting SSL certificates, Ruby, Mac OS X Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901864/troubleshooting-ssl-certificates-ruby-mac-os-x-yosemite/33035529#33035529)

[ruby was-sdk v2 : Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError Exception: SSL_connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318874/ruby-was-sdk-v2-seahorseclientnetworkingerror-exception-ssl-connect)

And tried various combinations of

```
Aws.use_bundled_cert!
```

and

```
Aws.config[:ssl_ca_bundle] = '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem'
```

Also re-installed Ruby, without binaries and updated x certs, as suggested in one of the SO questions above.

**Versions**

- Ruby: 2.4.2 / 2.5.0 (installed via RVM)
- Aws-Sdk: 3.0.1
- Paperclip: 5.2.1 (as well as the 6.0 version from master with only `aws-sdk-s3` gem)
- Rails: 5.1.4
- OS: OS X 10.12.6 (but same problem on Heroku - where I want to deploy to)

Comment: Do you have correct time on your system? Does this error happen with require 'open-uri'; open 'https://google.com'  for example?

Comment: well, `open("https://google.com")` works (need to add the protocol though).

Comment: Yes, `date` shows the correct time (using NTP) (also: it fails on heroku in the same way...I assume they have properly configured the clock)